# Does SPI got auto-increment mode by itself?

Tags: embedded, spi

I want to write and read to a few registers in one command via SPI
(from 0A to 0F). Does SPI support sth that I can do it in one command (auto-incrementing registers) and just write 6 bytes of data or I have to do it like:
`command for 0A -> data for 0A -> command for 0B -> data for 0B -> command for 0C ... ?`

Comment: You could do this by setting up a DMA table.

Answer (score 2):

The auto-increment mode you are describing does exist. It's even quite common.

However, it's not a feature of SPI but a feature of the chip / device you are communicating with.

So your question can only be answered for specific chips and devices. Check their datasheet.

Comment: I just checked that there is no information about any auto-increment available. But I wonder, cause I used STM32 HAL library and there reading/wirtiting > 1 byte by HAL_SPI_Read/Write works normally... How is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "works normally"? What happens? And what else did you expect to happen?

Comment: Works normally means that it just works, cause now I'm using MPSSE library with FTDI device and it is not working anymore :(